# can "map.tasks.maximum" improve my job latency?

Tags: hadoop

couldn't find a specific reference to this in the hadoop wiki...

Say I have a job that needs 100 mappers, no skew.
When I set the "map.tasks.maximum" to 100, hadoop waits till they all complete, and then shuffles (copy to the reducers), which takes time pending on network bandwidth.

If I would set the "map.tasks.maximum" to 10, there would be 10 generations of 10 mappers, and when each generation completes a shuffle of 1/10 of the data would be executed while the next generation of mappers is already working on the next records.

Would that really be more streamlined and improve my job's latency? is that even a worthy goal? would that come on expense of the clusters' throughput?

Answer (score 2):

I am doubt that it will improve your latency.  
My considerations are: 
Any reducer call can not finish until all mappers finishes - since it can not know that last mapper will not emit the same key. So I would not expect more work done before last mapper finishes
What I would try to do (without algorithm changes) is to give more memory for the shuffling to avoid spills to disk. 
You can also try compression of the intermediate data between mappers and reducers. 
In best of my understanding - data serialization is serious part of cost here - and if you can make it simper it might help.

Comment: so you're saying that network bandwidth is not the bottleneck here and if it is then compression is a better option?

Comment: There should be stage when network is bottlneck - to move bulk of sorted data between mappers and reducers. And here compression will help. But i think that serialization, spills to disk, etc takes heavier toll then simply move data via network. I can speculate that good serialization works in speed of a few MBs per second, while network move about 70...

Comment: I would also suggest defining a `Combiner` to reduce bandwidth usage, if your job can make use of one.